# How to let the model and random rotation 90 degree angle?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rotation

I can use cylinder to draw the tree (data is in picture one)(result is in picture one) , but now 
I don't know how to let the tree model random  rotation 90 degree angle

[image]

**first input point**

```
//input point 
//It is a,b,b,c,b,d......
//start point,end point,start point,end point....
const line_point =[0, 0, 0,
 2, 151, 2,
 2, 151, 2, 
 -62, 283, 63,
 2, 151, 2,
 62, 297, -58,
 -62, 283, 63,
 -104, 334, 74,
 -62, 283, 63,
 -58, 338,  45,
 62, 297, -58, 
 67, 403, -55,
 62, 297, -58,
 105, 365, -86];
```

**take out star point and end point**

```
const star_line_x= new Array();
const star_line_y= new Array();
const star_line_z= new Array();

const end_line_x= new Array();
const end_line_y= new Array();
const end_line_z= new Array();

for (var q=0; q < line_point.length; q+=6){
    star_line_x.push(line_point[q]);
}
for (var r=1; r < line_point.length; r+=6){
    star_line_y.push(line_point[r]);
}
for (var s=2; s < line_point.length; s+=6){
    star_line_z.push(line_point[s]);
}

for (var t=3; t < line_point.length; t+=6){
    end_line_x.push(line_point[t]);
}
for (var u=4; u < line_point.length; u+=6){
    end_line_y.push(line_point[u]);

}
for (var v=5; v < line_point.length; v+=6){

    end_line_z.push(line_point[v]);
}
var cylinder_star_point = new Array();
var cylinder_end_point = new Array();

//star_point end_point
for (var w=0; w < line_point.length/6; w++){

var star_point = new THREE.Vector3 (star_line_x[w],star_line_y[w],star_line_z[w]);
    var end_point = new THREE.Vector3 (end_line_x[w],end_line_y[w],end_line_z[w]);
    cylinder_star_point.push( star_point);
    cylinder_end_point.push( end_point);
}
```

**calculation cylinder high**

```
//calculation cylinder high
var line_len = new Array();
for (var dd=0; dd < line_point.length/6; dd++){
    var len_x = Math.pow(end_line_x[dd]-star_line_x[dd],2);
    var len_y = Math.pow(end_line_y[dd]-star_line_y[dd],2);
    var len_z = Math.pow(end_line_z[dd]-star_line_z[dd],2);
    var len_direction = Math.sqrt(len_x+len_y+len_z);
    line_len.push(len_direction);//Cylinder high

}
```

**calculation center point**

```
//center_point
const cylinder_center_point= new Array();
for (var bb=0; bb< cylinder_end_point.length; bb++){
    var star_set_point = cylinder_star_point[bb];
    var end_set_point = cylinder_end_point[bb];
    var center_point = end_set_point.clone().add(star_set_point).divideScalar(2);
    cylinder_center_point.push(center_point);
}
```

**calculation cylinder direction vector**

```
//cylinder direction
const cylinder_direction= new Array();
for (var cc=0; cc < cylinder_end_point.length; cc++){
    var star_direction = cylinder_star_point[cc];
    var end_direction = cylinder_end_point[cc];
    var center_direction  = end_direction.clone().sub(star_direction);
    cylinder_direction.push(center_direction);
}
```

**draw cylinder**

```
   for (var dd=0; dd <cylinder_direction.length;dd++){
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff0000'});
    let upVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);

    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, line_len[dd], 20, 1, false); 
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(0, line_len[dd]/2, 0);

    var group = new THREE.Group();
    group.position.set(star_line_x[dd],star_line_y[dd],star_line_z[dd]);
    group.add(mesh);

    let targetVector =cylinder_direction[dd];
    let quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(upVector, targetVector.normalize());
    group.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion) 
    scene.add(group)
}
```

**picture two**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the rotation.z of each cylinder mesh, or you can use the helper function called .lookAt( to make an object "point" toward a position in space.

Make sure the object is added to the scene first, before you use .lookAt().

Here is another way you can make a tree structure via recursion and object hierarchy:

https://three-tree-toy.glitch.me/

Comment: @manthraxThank you for your answer sincerely .I am having a hard time understanding it.Can you provided more details ?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example in glitch.. let me know if that helps?

Comment: @manthraxThank you for your answer. Sorry the  example for me is too complex.So if I want to  rotation the tree I need to rotation.Y and Z?

Comment: Instead of scene.add(group)

try:

treeGroup = new THREE.Group()

treeGroup.add(group)

scene.add(treeGroup)

treeGroup.rotation.y += Math.PI*Math.random()*2

Perhaps?

Comment: @manthraxThank you so so so much. I try to use the idea you talk me and  use  treeGroup.rotation.y= -Math.PI/2  ; than it is the  answer. Thank you for your help.